# How to freely move objects in Hub like Panorama

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am starting to transition from Windows Phone 7.8/8 to Windows Phone 8.1.

I want to create an universal app, but having some code problems.

For starters, the Hub is not behaving the same way as I expect it to.

In the panorama you could select a textblock or button and move it to where you want it positioned.

The Hub is not letting me do this... I can't select a button and move it.

Is there a setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can move it... but it is really tricky to get correctly.  Lets start out with the most simple `Hub` page you can have and put a button on it.

---

```XAML
<Grid>
    <Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" Header="application name">
        <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="SECTION 1">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>

        <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection2" Header="SECTION 2" >
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Click Me" Width="200" Height="300"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>

        <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection3" Header="SECTION 3">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

---

Now place your mouse cursor very slowly along the border of the `<Button>` you will see the mouse cursor will change to one with cross.  At that point you can move the `<Button>` as usual.  See pictures, I think the margin of error is about 2 pixels, so you must be accurate.

---

[image]

Zoomed in a bit more

[image]